# How to Synchronise phases of main and ups?

Tags: microcontroller

I need help to synchronise main AC phase with UPS phase so my ups change over time less than 8 ms and hence no restart occur in computer with pic pic micro controller?

Comment: Why do you think you need phase alignment in order to get a low switchover time? The two concepts are unrelated.

Comment: Because I read if you want to minimize switch over time you need phase alignment , ups also run in background in micro controller (not physically )while in charging mode, and when ac interrupt ups take over physically and with phase alignment we can get less switch over time . it happen in pure sine wave offline inverter.

Comment: We just need more information about what you are doing to help, this is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

1. If your microcontroller would reboot at an 8 ms brown-out of the mains power, then it means your power supply is underdimensioned. Increase your smoothing electrolytic capacitors.
2. Like Dave says phase is not important. If you switch fast from the mains to a UPS power supply which is 90° out of phase the transformer will have a very small hick-up, but the high inductance will make sure there won't be sudden changes in current.

Comment: Now my ups, give different switch over time i.e 6ms to 100ms, but I want, my ups to give fix 6 ms switch over time , how can I achieve, fix 6 ms switch over time or less. my inverter is a pure sine pwm based inverter (pic16f73 with 20MHz crystal).

Comment: Problem is only from switch over, Main AC to UPS power.